# jQuery click function to slidedown div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the the [forkit](https://github.com/hakimel/forkit.js) jQuery ribbon that drops down a curtain of additional content. I have managed to apply this  and it works fine once the ribbon is pulled down as per the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eaj5rvtm/).

I want to modify it such that, the curtain also appears once a button is clicked.

Kindly help.

jQuery:

```
(function(){

var STATE_CLOSED = 0,
    STATE_DETACHED = 1,
    STATE_OPENED = 2,

    TAG_HEIGHT = 30,
    TAG_WIDTH = 200,
    MAX_STRAIN = 40,

    // Factor of page height that needs to be dragged for the 
    // curtain to fall
    DRAG_THRESHOLD = 0.36;

    VENDORS = [ 'Webkit', 'Moz', 'O', 'ms' ];

var dom = {
        ribbon: null,
        ribbonString: null,
        ribbonTag: null,
        curtain: null,
        closeButton: null
    },

    // The current state of the ribbon
    state = STATE_CLOSED,

    // Ribbon text, correlates to states
    closedText = '',
    detachedText = '',

    friction = 1.04;
    gravity = 1.5,

    // Resting position of the ribbon when curtain is closed
    closedX = TAG_WIDTH * 0.4,
    closedY = -TAG_HEIGHT * 0.5,

    // Resting position of the ribbon when curtain is opened
    openedX = TAG_WIDTH * 0.4,
    openedY = TAG_HEIGHT,

    velocity = 0,
    rotation = 45,

    curtainTargetY = 0,
    curtainCurrentY = 0,

    dragging = false,
    dragTime = 0,
    dragY = 0,

    anchorA = new Point( closedX, closedY ),
    anchorB = new Point( closedX, closedY ),

    mouse = new Point();

function initialize() {

    dom.ribbon = document.querySelector( '.forkit' );
    dom.curtain = document.querySelector( '.forkit-curtain' );
    dom.closeButton = document.querySelector( '.forkit-curtain .close-button' );

    if( dom.ribbon ) {

        // Fetch label texts from DOM
        closedText = dom.ribbon.getAttribute( 'data-text' ) || '';
        detachedText = dom.ribbon.getAttribute( 'data-text-detached' ) || closedText;

        // Construct the sub-elements required to represent the 
        // tag and string that it hangs from
        dom.ribbon.innerHTML = '<span class="string"></span><span class="tag">' + closedText + '</span>';
        dom.ribbonString = dom.ribbon.querySelector( '.string' );
        dom.ribbonTag = dom.ribbon.querySelector( '.tag' );

        // Bind events
        dom.ribbon.addEventListener( 'click', onRibbonClick, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', layout, false );

        if( dom.closeButton ) {
            dom.closeButton.addEventListener( 'click', onCloseClick, false );
        }

        // Start the animation loop
        animate();

    }

}

function onMouseDown( event ) {
    if( dom.curtain && state === STATE_DETACHED ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        dragY = event.clientY;
        dragTime = Date.now();
        dragging = true;

    }
}

function onMouseMove( event ) {
    mouse.x = event.clientX;
    mouse.y = event.clientY;
}

function onMouseUp( event ) {
    if( state !== STATE_OPENED ) {
        state = STATE_CLOSED;
        dragging = false;
    }
}

function onRibbonClick( event ) {
    if( dom.curtain ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if( state === STATE_OPENED ) {
            close();
        }
        else if( Date.now() - dragTime < 300 ) {
            open();
        }
    }
}

function onCloseClick( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    close();
}

function layout() {
    if( state === STATE_OPENED ) {
        curtainTargetY = window.innerHeight;
        curtainCurrentY = curtainTargetY;
    }
}

function open() {
    dragging = false;
    state = STATE_OPENED;
}

function close() {
    dragging = false;
    state = STATE_CLOSED;
    dom.ribbonTag.innerHTML = closedText;
}

function detach() {
    state = STATE_DETACHED;
    dom.ribbonTag.innerHTML = detachedText;
}

function animate() {
    update();
    render();

    requestAnimFrame( animate );
}

function update() {
    // Distance between mouse and top right corner
    var distance = distanceBetween( mouse.x, mouse.y, window.innerWidth, 0 );

    // If we're OPENED the curtainTargetY should ease towards page bottom
    if( state === STATE_OPENED ) {
        curtainTargetY = Math.min( curtainTargetY + ( window.innerHeight - curtainTargetY ) * 0.2, window.innerHeight );
    }
    else {

        // Detach the tag when hovering close enough
        if( distance < TAG_WIDTH * 1.5 ) {
            detach();
        }
        // Re-attach the tag if the user moved away
        else if( !dragging && state === STATE_DETACHED && distance > TAG_WIDTH * 2 ) {
            close();
        }

        if( dragging ) {
            // Updat the curtain position while dragging
            curtainTargetY = Math.max( mouse.y - dragY, 0 );

            // If the threshold is crossed, open the curtain
            if( curtainTargetY > window.innerHeight * DRAG_THRESHOLD ) {
                open();
            }
        }
        else {
            curtainTargetY *= 0.8;
        }

    }

    // Ease towards the target position of the curtain
    curtainCurrentY += ( curtainTargetY - curtainCurrentY ) * 0.3;

    // If we're dragging or detached we need to simulate 
    // the physical behavior of the ribbon
    if( dragging || state === STATE_DETACHED ) {

        // Apply forces
        velocity /= friction;
        velocity += gravity;

        var containerOffsetX = dom.ribbon.offsetLeft;

        var offsetX = Math.max( ( ( mouse.x - containerOffsetX ) - closedX ) * 0.2, -MAX_STRAIN );

        anchorB.x += ( ( closedX + offsetX ) - anchorB.x ) * 0.1;
        anchorB.y += velocity;

        var strain = distanceBetween( anchorA.x, anchorA.y, anchorB.x, anchorB.y );

        if( strain > MAX_STRAIN ) {
            velocity -= Math.abs( strain ) / ( MAX_STRAIN * 1.25 );
        }

        var dy = Math.max( mouse.y - anchorB.y, 0 ),
            dx = mouse.x - ( containerOffsetX + anchorB.x );

        // Angle the ribbon towards the mouse but limit it avoid extremes
        var angle = Math.min( 130, Math.max( 50, Math.atan2( dy, dx ) * 180 / Math.PI ) );

        rotation += ( angle - rotation ) * 0.1;
    }
    // Ease ribbon towards the OPENED state
    else if( state === STATE_OPENED ) {
        anchorB.x += ( openedX - anchorB.x ) * 0.2;
        anchorB.y += ( openedY - anchorB.y ) * 0.2;

        rotation += ( 90 - rotation ) * 0.02;
    }
    // Ease ribbon towards the CLOSED state
    else {
        anchorB.x += ( anchorA.x - anchorB.x ) * 0.2;
        anchorB.y += ( anchorA.y - anchorB.y ) * 0.2;

        rotation += ( 45 - rotation ) * 0.2;
    }
}

function render() {

    if( dom.curtain ) {
        dom.curtain.style.top = - 100 + Math.min( ( curtainCurrentY / window.innerHeight ) * 100, 100 ) + '%';
    }

    dom.ribbon.style[ prefix( 'transform' ) ] = transform( 0, curtainCurrentY, 0 );
    dom.ribbonTag.style[ prefix( 'transform' ) ] = transform( anchorB.x, anchorB.y, rotation );

    var dy = anchorB.y - anchorA.y,
        dx = anchorB.x - anchorA.x;

    var angle = Math.atan2( dy, dx ) * 180 / Math.PI;

    dom.ribbonString.style.width = anchorB.y + 'px';
    dom.ribbonString.style[ prefix( 'transform' ) ] = transform( anchorA.x, 0, angle );

}

function prefix( property, el ) {
    var propertyUC = property.slice( 0, 1 ).toUpperCase() + property.slice( 1 );

    for( var i = 0, len = VENDORS.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var vendor = VENDORS[i];

        if( typeof ( el || document.body ).style[ vendor + propertyUC ] !== 'undefined' ) {
            return vendor + propertyUC;
        }
    }

    return property;
}

function transform( x, y, r ) {
    return 'translate('+x+'px,'+y+'px) rotate('+r+'deg)';
}

function distanceBetween( x1, y1, x2, y2 ) {
    var dx = x1-x2;
    var dy = y1-y2;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

/**
 * Defines a 2D position.
 */
function Point( x, y ) {
    this.x = x || 0; 
    this.y = y || 0;
}

Point.prototype.distanceTo = function( x, y ) {
    var dx = x-this.x;
    var dy = y-this.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
};

Point.prototype.clone = function() {
    return new Point( this.x, this.y );
};

Point.prototype.interpolate = function( x, y, amp ) {
    this.x += ( x - this.x ) * amp;
    this.y += ( y - this.y ) * amp;
};

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame        ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame  ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame     ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame       ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame      ||
            function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
})();

initialize();

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event handler to a button that calls the open() method from the forkit plugin, like this:

```
$('#dropButton').bind('click', function(){
    open();
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martiensk/eaj5rvtm/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to it - should work.

```
$('a.forkit').click(function(){
$('.forkit-curtain').slideDown();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eaj5rvtm/1/